# jsp forward not working as expected

Tags: jsp, forward

I have jsp depending on some condition I am doing forward to another page.

I have /myjsp/first.jsp which has code as,

```
<%
if(some condtion){
   somelogic                
}
else
{
       application.getRequestDispatcher("/myjsp/another.jsp").forward(request,response);
}
%>
<div>
    <jsp:include page='header.jsp' />
</div>
```

In this code if flow comes to else condition control is going to another.jsp.

But also it is displaying below div tag from /myjsp/first.jsp.

I want to keep control on another.jsp once it goes there and it should not show anything from current page ie div tag  from /myjsp/first.jsp

Answer (score 1):

Put the `div` inside the `if`.

Or even better, don't use scriptlets, and don't forward from a JSP. JSPs should be used as view components, and generate markup only. Workflow should be done from inside a servlet or action of your preferred MVC framework.

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
<jsp:forward page="pageName.jsp"></jsp:forward>
```

instead of
application.getRequestDispatcher("/myjsp/another.jsp").forward(request,response);

or

response.sendRedirect("pagenName.jsp");

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
    response.sendRedirect();
```

instead

```
     forward();
```

I think it will solve your problem.

Comment: No it won't. A forward and a redirect are two completely different things.

Answer (score 0):

I agree, you should not use 'forward' (or sendRedirect) in a jsp because with scriptlets there are HTML code in the response buffer, it's possible to fix (or hide) the issue by increasing the buffer size with <%@ page autoFlush="true" buffer="2000kb"%>; what I do is using JavaBeans instead.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverFlow. You should learn how to [write a good answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). And I wanna let you know that you are answering to a question which is asked 2 years ago. I suggest you to have a look at [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) first.